# Drive not showing in ubuntu server

Tags: mount, ssd

I recently got a new sabrent 2tb rocket Gen 4 ssd and a sabrent ssd enclosure for my mini pc. The mini pc is running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I formatted the drive the first time in windows as nfts and plugged it into the mini pc. Everything was fine until the drive disappeared. I ran lsblk. Nothing. I ran df -H to see if it was still mounted. Nope. I ran fdisk -l and finally saw it. Except... It was all 0s, the I'd, the size.

I took it out, reformatted it with exFat this time and took it back. Same thing, it works and then it's just gone. Rebooting doesn't help, no firmware upgrades to be had, no issues in windows...

I don't know what's going on. When it was working, I mounted it and then used mergerfs to create a pool. But the first time I didn't do that and it still happened. Logs don't show anything except asking for cache data failing.

Please, could anyone help me. I've looked for over 2 days and can't find a fix.

```
usb-storage USB Mass Storage device detected host: usb-storage Direct-Access
Sabrent
1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6 Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0 
[sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [sdb] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[sdb] Add. Sense: Invaild command operation code 
[sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B) 
[sdb] 0-byte physical blocks  
[sdb] Test W failed, assume Write Enabled 
[sdb] Asking for cache data failed 
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```